# Unexpected token '@' when using ES6 decorators

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a React project setup and I'm trying to incorporate MobX into it. With that I have to use decorators i.e.

```
@observable
```

When I do that though I get the following error:

https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx

> Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (5:22)
>
> class ListStore {
>       @observable items = ['Pete', 'John', 'Henry', 'Jeff', 'Bob'];
>   }

My Webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/App.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy']
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
        }]
    }
};
```

My ESLint config:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
            "ecmaVersion": 6,
            "ecmaFeatures": {
                "jsx": true
            },
            "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "env": {
            "browser": true,
            "node": true,
            "es6": false
    },
    "ecmaFeatures": {
            "modules": true
    },
    "rules": {
        "strict": [
            2,
            "global"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            2,
            "single"
        ],
        "indent": [
            2,
            4
        ],
        "eqeqeq": [
            2,
            "smart"
        ],
        "semi": [
            2,
            "always"
        ],
        "max-depth": [
            2,
            4
        ],
        "max-statements": [
            2,
            15
        ],
        "complexity": [
            2,
            5
        ]
    }
}
```

As a note, I'm new to using Webpack as well as utilising ESLint, so this might very well be a newby question. However after doing research online I haven't find anything that's worked. (This includes installing the 'transform-decorators-legacy' Babel plugin).

Comment: Did you check this boilerplate code? Maybe it's a bit outdated, but it might have some packages that you don't have in your packages.json (which you might also add to the post?) https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-boilerplate

Comment: Well, that's because decorators aren't in ES6. They're still a proposal only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the issue isn't so much the decorator, but the property initializer syntax. It'll probably fail on this as well:

```
class ListStore {
  items = ['Pete', 'John', 'Henry', 'Jeff', 'Bob']
}
```

To support those, you can add the `transform-class-properties` plugin:

```
$ npm install babel-plugin-transform-class-properties --save
```

(and update your Webpack config accordingly)

Or use a Babel preset that includes it (`stage-2`, `stage-1` or `stage-0`).