# SyntaxError: Unexpected token when using react-aim package

Tags: reactjs, syntax-error

I'm using [react-aim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-aim) package, but when running webpack I get this error:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (6:0)
```

It's becuase of `@target(` which is the same as their own example. Am I missing something.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672474/unexpected-token-when-using-es6-decorators

Comment: @JasonSpradlin Isn't this a node related error? I'm using this IDE (VSCode) in another project with exactly the same code and it's working.

Comment: yeah, it probably has to do with your babel configuration not knowing that it needs to support decorators.